# MyOwnFreeHost API Client Area Infinityfree

Tags: api

I've been trying to use this [code](https://github.com/InfinityFreeHosting/mofh-client) on my local environment. I saved it as a php script and when I run it, it says:

> Failed to create account: The domain name **(the-domain-I-used.com)** is allready added to a hosting account. .

I don't want it to create an account with my domain, I want it to allow users to type their domain in. How do I do this?